# slow mysql query to get product id and its category id

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with this simple sql query that runs out of memory my server:

```
SELECT p.product_id, c.category_id 
FROM product p, product_to_category ptc, category c     
WHERE p.status = "1" AND     
p.product_id = ptc.product_id AND
c.category_id = ptc.category_id
GROUP BY p.product_id;
```

What is wrong with it? I just want to get product id and what category is the product.

Comment: Do you have these columns indexed?

Comment: dont use group by .. try wih distinct

Comment: distinct instead of group returns wrong result

Comment: If you have a product with 2 categories, which category you want to return the query? (e.g. product 1 has linked with A and B categories)

Comment: I don't have such, 1 product is assoc to 1 category only

Comment: In this case your schema is incorrect. You don't need `product_to_category` table. Simple add a `category_id` foreign key on `product` table.

Comment: this is OS platform used, better not to change tables :)

Comment: it seems this was a server problem because it is now working with this little changed sql: SELECT p.product_id, ptc.category_id 
FROM product p, product_to_category ptc     
WHERE p.status="1" 
    AND p.product_id=ptc.product_id

Comment: Marcus,after miltos comment I checked (after I repplied to him) and discovered that there are several products associated with few categories which now returns value to miltos question - how can I have all categories listed with each product? If I remove group clause it wil probably returns huge numbers of rows? how to fix it?

Comment: can you explain "how can I have all categories listed with each product?" What you want, in one row, getting all categories?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45721/discussion-between-miltos-and-thecore7)

Comment: I mean to have different row for each product to category association when products is asoc to more than 1 category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `category` table.

```
SELECT p.product_id, ptc.category_id 
FROM product p, product_to_category ptc     
WHERE p.status="1" 
    AND p.product_id=ptc.product_id
```

And with join

```
SELECT p.product_id, ptc.category_id 
FROM product p
JOIN product_to_category ptc  
    ON p.product_id=ptc.product_id 
WHERE p.status="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems very unlikely that your query would have such poor performance.  But, you can start by using explicit `join` syntax to make the query easier to understand:

```
SELECT p.product_id, c.category_id 
FROM product p join
     product_to_category ptc
     on p.product_id = ptc.product_id join
     category c 
     on c.category_id = ptc.category_id   
WHERE p.status="1" 
GROUP BY p.product_id;
```

Some possibilities:

- If you missed one of the conditions in the `where` clause, you could be generating lots of rows.
- Your tables are inordinately large for the system you are working on.
- Your are actually running out of temporary storage space for the aggregation, and your temporary space is full